# Can't get batch to logout when it's done

Tags: batch-file

I have a .bat that I've wrote to automate an install of a piece of software I have to install all the time at work. (I can't use powershell because a lot of the machines are XP still)

Near the end, the script is supposed to clean itself up and and logout, but I can't get it to log out for some reason.

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe>nul 2>&1
set _sd=%~dp0
cd /d c:\
del "%_sd%md5sum.exe"
...
del "%_sd%RUN-AS-ADMIN.bat"
wait 2
shutdown -f -l
```

Comment: wait is not a valid command.

Comment: Doesn't `shutdown` default to a 20 second timeout before it continues? You can change the length of time by using the `-t xx` parameter.

Comment: Can't use logout with -t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `wait` command in CMD. There is `timeout` for Win7+ but not for XP. To implement a kind of a timeout you'll have to use for example `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul`. This will make your system "wait" for 5 seconds. You can modify the timeout by replacing 6 with any other value. If you want a timeout of X seconds, replace 6 with X+1.

Comment: Oh... What in the world was I thinking? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: Made a stupid mistake making this, fixed it up.**

Try this instead:

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe>nul 2>&1
set _sd=%~dp0
cd /d c:\
del "%_sd%md5sum.exe"
...
del "%_sd%RUN-AS-ADMIN.bat"
pause
shutdown -f -l
```

All I did was make it so that the `wait` is replaced with `pause`

I did some looking around, and I couldn't find any native commands that make the batch file delay and automatically continue, so this is the closest I can find. (Assuming the computer you're using this on is a Windows XP)

If you don't use a Windows XP for the batch file, use this instead:

```
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe>nul 2>&1
set _sd=%~dp0
cd /d c:\
del "%_sd%md5sum.exe"
...
del "%_sd%RUN-AS-ADMIN.bat"
timeout /t 2 >nul
shutdown -f -l
```

The `timeout` acts as a delay, however, it is unfortunately not a native command on Windows XP, but it is on Windows 7+ (Unsure about vista)
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Excuse me. What Windows version supported `wait` command, so it is now a "discontinued one"?

Comment: My apologies. I read something a while back and I guess it was for a different command. Wait isn't a command and as far as I know it never existed as a native command. Very sorry, I'll fix my post.